# How to read file that is either uncompressed or compressed with gzip?

Tags: file, rust, gzip

I try to read the contents of a file. The function doing this should be able to open the file regardless if it is a plain text file or a gzip-compressed file.

Below I have a working example, but if the file happens to be a plain text file, I have to read it twice. The function first tries to open the file assuming it is gzip-compressed (using the `flate2` crate). If that does not provid a valid header, the file is read once more as a normal text file.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Read};

use flate2::read::GzDecoder;


fn read_file( path: &str ) -> () {
    let f_obj = File::open( path )
        .expect( "Could not read file." );

    let mut text = String::new();

    let mut gz = GzDecoder::new( io::BufReader::new( &f_obj ) );

    match gz.header() {
        // `path` points to a file that is gzip-compressed.
        Some( _ ) => gz.read_to_string( &mut text ),  
        // `path` points to a plain text file.
        None => {  
            // Since the `GzDecoder` already moved some bytes out of f_obj 
            // by trying to decompress it, the file must be read once more.
            // TODO There may be a better way instead of reading the same 
            // file twice.
            let mut f_obj = File::open( path )
                .expect( "Could not read file." );
            f_obj.read_to_string( &mut text )
        },
    }.unwrap();

    for line in text.lines() {
        println!( "{:?}", line );
    }
}


fn main() {
    read_file( "file.txt.gz" )
}
```

Is there better way to do this?

I am relatively new to Rust and come from a Python background, so maybe I have the wrong perspective solving this problem, but I assume, this is not the best solution.

Comment: You should be able to seek back to the beginning of the file without needing to reopen it.

Comment: See https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html

Comment: Thanks. `f_obj.rewind();` did the trick.

Comment: I would use an enum: one compressed, and one uncompressed with a `read()` method that decompresses or reads the raw file depending on variant. Then I would read the first 10 bytes of the file looking for the gzip header; and set the file type variant accordingly.